# PHP Web Service vs mySQL Connector on Windows Application

Tags: c#, .net, php, mysql, web-services

I have a Windows Application in C#.  This application interacts with a remote mySQL database.  Should I create a PHP web service to do these (insert/add/delete/update) or use mySQL connector for c#?  I'm not sure which way is better.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably define 'remote' in terms of your logical/physical execution environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wether the MySQL server is in the same network (*phisically*) or not. From my point of view the according solution would be to create a **dedicated Web-Service** that provides you the CRUD functionality for your application.

This, because it gives you some [Separation of Concerns (SoC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) as you can separate business logic tier from the data access tier.

See also: [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) | "In object-oriented programming, the single responsibility principle states that every object should have a single responsibility, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class. All its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility."

Every part of your application serves a specific purpose which makes it easier to maintain over a big timespan.

Now this sounds pretty nice and cool, but do we really need to abstract everything away?

As with everything else, **it depends**.

---

Here is a little Use-Case:

- The Database needs to be modified: Tables keys are removed, new tables are added old tables are removed.

What will you, as developer, need to do in order to keep your application working?

**Using MySQLConnector:**
Start *"hacking"* inside your source code and making sure all queries run as expected. And if something goes wrong during that process, it will be a pain to fix it because it's all kind of nested within the application logic.

**Using a dedicated Web-Service:**
Just make sure your methods are updated to match the new database design | No need to change anything on the application-side [except method arguments in some cases].

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Why use PHP web-service when the application is in c# ? just use the MySql connector for C#. 
Secondly web-service performance will be slow compared to MySql connector for C#.